# Myget packages not showing in feed despite successful upload

Tags: nuget, myget

I have been successfully posting packages to a personal (public) MyGet for weeks. Last successful push was `Monday 10th`, 4 days ago.

Today, I have pushed over a dozen different packages to a variety of feeds using the same approach. All pushes have been successful and return `201 Created`. I know they have been created because doing a subsequent push returns `409 Conflict` with the same version.

[image]

None of them have appeared in my MyGet feed via either CLI search or the MyGet UI, nor is any activity showing in the MyGet Activity Feed. Last activity is from `Monday 10th`.

I've tried running the following: nuget list Template -PreRelease -IncludeDelisted -AllVersions -source  https://www.myget.org/F/tr-public/api/v3/index.json

Only the previously existing packages (`Template.TestedLibrary`) are visible.

I've confirmed the packages are all valid, I can reference the created artefacts from a local folder and create all the templates, install dependencies etc from a local package source.

As far as I can tell, my build is green, my pack and push is green, the packages are valid, they exist on the server (as I can't overwrite them) but they just don't appear anywhere and I can't find them in any search.

Update: I have also uploaded the package manually through the MyGet UI, gotten the Green Success message, but again, still not showing up in the feed. Same story if I try and upload it a second time, it also already exists.

Any thoughts on what could cause this?

Answer (score 0):

> Any thoughts on what could cause this?

Answer: MyGet

Just took over 24 hours for the packages to show up, possibly because I accidently included some binaries in one.